# Flawed logic in A* implementation

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I've been using examples of others' implementations of the A* pathfinding algorithm as a crutch to help me write my first implementation. I'm having some trouble with the logic in one of the more readable examples I've found.

I'm not here to pick apart this code, really, **I'm trying to figure out if I am right or if I am misunderstanding the mechanics here.** If I need to review how A* works I will but if this code is incorrect I need to find other sources to learn from.

It appears to me that the **logic** found here is **flawed in two places** both contained here:

```
for(Node neighbor : current.getNeighborList()) {
    neighborIsBetter;
    //if we have already searched this Node, don't bother and continue to the next 
    if (closedList.contains(neighbor))
        continue;

    //also just continue if the neighbor is an obstacle
    if (!neighbor.isObstacle) {

        // calculate how long the path is if we choose this neighbor as the next step in the path 
        float neighborDistanceFromStart = (current.getDistanceFromStart() + map.getDistanceBetween(current, neighbor));

        //add neighbor to the open list if it is not there
        if(!openList.contains(neighbor)) {
-->         openList.add(neighbor);
            neighborIsBetter = true;
            //if neighbor is closer to start it could also be better
-->     } else if(neighborDistanceFromStart < current.getDistanceFromStart()) {
            neighborIsBetter = true;
        } else {
            neighborIsBetter = false;
        }
        // set neighbors parameters if it is better
        if (neighborIsBetter) {
            neighbor.setPreviousNode(current);
            neighbor.setDistanceFromStart(neighborDistanceFromStart);
            neighbor.setHeuristicDistanceFromGoal(heuristic.getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(neighbor.getX(), neighbor.getY(), map.getGoalLocationX(), map.getGoalLocationY()));
        }
    }
}
```

[source](https://code.google.com/p/a-star-java/source/browse/AStar/src/aStar/AStar.java?r=7)

The first line I marked (-->), seems incorrect to me. If you look at the [implementation of the list being used](https://code.google.com/p/a-star-java/source/browse/AStar/src/aStar/Node.java?r=7)(below) it sorts based on `heuristicDistanceFromGoal` which is set several lines below the `.add`.

```
public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
    float thisTotalDistanceFromGoal = heuristicDistanceFromGoal + distanceFromStart;
    float otherTotalDistanceFromGoal = otherNode.getHeuristicDistanceFromGoal() + otherNode.getDistanceFromStart();

    if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal < otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) {
        return -1;
    } else if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal > otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The second line I marked should always evaluate to false. It reads:

`} else if(neighborDistanceFromStart < current.getDistanceFromStart()) {`

Which can be simplified to:

```
if((current.getDistanceFromStart() + map.getDistanceBetween(current, neighbor)) < current.getDistanceFromStart())
```

And again to:

`if(map.getDistanceBetween(current, neighbor) < 0)`

Which would be fine except `getDistanceBetween()` should always return a positive value ([see here](https://code.google.com/p/a-star-java/source/browse/AStar/src/aStar/AreaMap.java?r=7)).

Am I on or off track?

Comment: StackOverflow is designed for users who have issues with their code and to get help to fix it. It is not the place for debates about other peoples code.

Comment: Perhaps I need to reframe the question. In essence I don't care if this persons code is logical. I really want to know if I understand A*. Since I think I do and this doesn't look like quite right to me (but doesn't look altogether wrong) I'm trying to find out whether I'm confused or on track.

Comment: At first you would have a datastructure that would define the map, but you use another data structure to hold only the close neighbors to your current position, if the neighbor is not in the list add it, if it is see if the neighbors value is less than current value, if the neighbor is better than your current position assign the boolean to true and attempt to make that the new position. But yes i suppose you do raise a good question, but there is a section dedicated to code reviews

Comment: for example this link is the place you should of submitted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I'll post it there next time. Is there a convenient way to migrate?

Comment: not that i am aware of, copying and pasting it is probably the only way.

Comment: @tommyknocker Code Review only allows questions on code that the poster wrote himself. It also only allows questions on code believed to be correct.

Comment: I have no knowledge of these A* heuristics so I thought I read about it [here](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html). I compared what it said under "Euclidean distance, squared" with [ClosestHeuristic.java](https://code.google.com/p/a-star-java/source/browse/AStar/src/aStar/heuristics/ClosestHeuristic.java?r=7). The article says "do not use" but as far as I can see, it is being used. I think you are on to something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are mostly on track. I strongly suspect the code you posted is still under development and has some problems. But, still your assumption of distance is positive is not correct in general. A* is a graph search algorithm and edges can have negative weights as well in general. Hence, I assume they tried to implement the most general case. The openList.add seems totally fine to me though. Your queue should be sorted with heuristic distance. Just check the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star, the related line is                 f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal). And, main idea behind this is, you always underestimate the distance (admissible heuristic); hence, if the goal is found, none of the not-explored nodes can be optimal. You can read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic

Second of all, If you want a stable AI code base, You can simply use http://code.google.com/p/aima-java/. It is the implementation of the algorithms in AIMA (Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach)